# EXCEPTION Multiple dex files define - Android Studio

Tags: android

Can anyone please help me with this? I dont know what does this mean. To give you a back up I updated my sdk with 23 and then i got 101 errors regarding HTTPClient not being resolved.

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Akula\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\NewAndroidstudioworkspace\ToReachMe\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=D:\NewAndroidstudioworkspace\ToReachMe\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 9.118 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Please, show `build.gradle` file also.

Answer (score 1):

add code in gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        ..
        ..
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```